# build objects in for loop with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically build an object for every iteration of a for loop using the i as part of the object name. based on the example below I would like 19 objects with names: obj0, obj1, obj2... obj18.

so I have an array with a length:

```
    console.log(foo.length); // 19

    for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
        var bar+i  = {}; 
    };
    console.log(bar1);
    console.log(bar2);
    // ...
    console.log(bar18);
```

I can't figure out the correct syntax for "`var bar+i = {};`", obviously it does not work.

**EDIT**
I really need objects because I am constructing data to be used in D3.js that needs to be an array of many objects

Comment: Perhaps you should be creating an **array**.

Comment: Is there any reason these need to be global?  Or not in an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless `bar{i}` is an array value / object property itself the only way to do this is to bind it to the window or root object.

```
window[bar+i] = {};
```

Or to the root object

```
this[bar+i] = {};
```

Much better to bind it to an array / object itself though rather than bind senselessly to the root/window.

```
var array = [];

array[bar+i] = {};
```

Comment: Binding to an array is just what I needed to do, your third comment did just the trick, with one small change: array["bar"+i] = {};

Answer (score 2):

There are some hacks how you can achieve this. However I advice you to use arrays instead of that method you are trying to use:

```
 console.log(foo.length); // 19

 var variables = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    variables[i]  = {}; 
 };
 console.log(variables[0]);
 console.log(variables[1]);
 // ...
 console.log(variables[18]);
```

Comment: He doesn't have to use arrays. He can use an object instead... but yeah.. the rest is correct.

Comment: Creating an array from literal (`[]`) is faster then `new Array()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create variables like this.

What you can do is add properties of the global scope, which you can use as variables:

```
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  window['bar'+i ] = {}; 
};
```

or use another object to hold everything:

```
var container = {};
for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  container['bar'+i] = {}; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically write variable names, but you can do the same on object properties:

```
console.log(foo.length); // 19

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
    obj[ 'bar' + i ] = {}; 
};

console.log(obj.bar1);
console.log(obj.bar2);
// ...
console.log(obj.bar18);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval:

```
eval('var bar'+i+' = {};');
```

But really, you shouldn't be doing this, unless you know for sure you can't do it the other way.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it's kind-of like, "Well, you can do it by putting on the One Ring of Power, but please don't because MORDOR."

Comment: @Pointy Because MORDOR will get you?