# How to create a new variable within a for-loop

Tags: javascript

I want to create new variables in a for-loop where the variable-name shall contain the index of the loop: pos_1, pos_2...

So I try that:

```
for(i=1; i<=slide_length;i++){
    var pos_[i] = 49*i;
}
```

But that doesn't create anything. What do I do wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to learn more about Javascript, Programming languages, Datatypes, Variables, Etc instead of trying to program without any clue of what you're doing.

Comment: @Ele totally agree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [build objects in for loop with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569551/build-objects-in-for-loop-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window["variable_name"]` to create global variables.

```js
var slide_length = 5;
for(i=1; i<=slide_length;i++){
    window["pos_"+i] = 49*i;
}

console.log(pos_5);
```

Answer (score 0):

create the array outside the loop.

```
var pos_ = []
for(i=1; i<=slide_length;i++){
    pos_.push(49*i);
}
```

then `pos_` has your values after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an array:

```
function createVariables(){
  var pos = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= slide_length; ++i) {
      pos[i] = 49*i;
  }

  return pos;
}
```

You then have access to `pos[0]` through `pos[slide_length]`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be useful to you,

```js
 var slide_length = 10;
 for(i=1; i<=slide_length;i++){
     this['pos_'+i] = 49 * i;       
 }
     console.log(pos_1);
     console.log(pos_8);
     console.log(pos_10);
```